# onCreateViewHolder not called when a new item is added

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, wear-os

I'm developing my first application on Android Wear.

The phone sends data thanks to `Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem()`. The watch retrieves the data in a `WearableListenerService`.

The main `WearableActivity` starts this `Service` and registers a `Receiver` to it in order to get every new data dynamically.

Then, I want to add every new data in a `WearableListView.Adapter`.

Everything is working perfectly. The MainActivity gets all the required data and add it to the adapter.

The thing is that none of the item that I add are displayed.

Here's the code of my MainActivity as the issue comes probably from the Adapter.

```
public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {
private WearableListView mListView;
private DataReceiver mDataReceiver;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    mDataReceiver = new DataReceiver();
    mDataReceiver.setListener(new DataReceiver.DataReceivedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataReceived(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            myAdapter.addItem(jsonObject);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ListenerService.GET_PHONE_DATA_ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mDataReceiver, intentFilter);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListenerService.class);
    startService(intent);
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mListView = (WearableListView) findViewById(R.id.wearable_list);
        MyAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class MyAdapter extends WearableListView.Adapter {
    private List<JSONObject> mList;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public MyAdapter (Context context) {
        mList= ArrayList<>();
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void addItem(JSONObject item) {
        mList.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ItemViewHolder extends WearableListView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView1;
        private TextView textView2;
        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView1= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            textView2= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public WearableListView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ItemViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WearableListView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemViewHolder itemHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;
        TextView textView1 = itemHolder.textView1;
        TextView textView2 = itemHolder.textView2;
        JSONObject item;
        try {
            item = mList.get(position);
            textView1.setText(item.getString("title"));
            textView2.setText(item.getString("name"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("MyAdapter", e.getMessage());
        }
        holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("Test", "SIZE ==" + mList.size());
        return mList.size();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mDataReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}

public static class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public interface DataReceivedListener {
        void onDataReceived(JSONObject jsonObject);
    }
    private DataReceivedListener mDataReceivedListener;

    public void setListener(DataReceivedListener dataReceivedListener) {
        mDataReceivedListener = dataReceivedListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("data") != null) {
            if (mDataReceivedListener != null) {
                try {
                    mDataReceivedListener.onDataReceived(new JSONObject(intent.getStringExtra("data")));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("DataReceiver", "Could not read JSON data");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I put Log on `onBindViewHolder` in order to get the JSONObject at the current position, the result seems to be legit. Even `getItemCount` is coherent.

The thing is that onCreateViewHolder is only called twice and nothing is displayed on the ListView.

What am I doing wrong ? I tried a lot of things, patches, etc. but it only made everything worse.

EDIT : Here's the layout

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/container"

    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_box="all">

        <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
            android:id="@+id/album_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

[image]
Here is the HierarchyViewer result. Name of the variables (textviews) are different but it's the same code.

The TextViews are correctly filled with the relevant data.

Comment: can you post the layout?

Comment: @Blackbelt, my bad, totally forgot about it! Please see the edited answer.

Comment: so what do you see: SIZE == ? also add `Log.d` in `onBindViewHolder` with the `position`

Comment: @pskink, the size increments until no other value is sent by the phone (in this case, it shows 26).

Comment: what about `onBindViewHolder` ?

Comment: I removed this from the code but the log from onBindViewHolder of the variable "item" shows me JSON data, each time a JSONObject is added. These values are coherent. That's why I don't understand why onCreateViewHolder is almost never called and why nothing is displayed

Comment: did you try running hierarchyviewer ?

Comment: @pskink please see my updated question for the hierarchyviewer screenshot

Comment: there is another window that displays the screen and color rectangles showing the view boundaries / frames, can you see them? what are their size / position ? also 2 children is imho ok as for wearable screen, dont you think? how many items do you expect to see at once?

Comment: @pskink I updated the screenshot with all the content of Hierarchy Viewer. As you said, we can see the two children. The WearableListView is located at x = 46 and y = 46. And yes, two children is perfectly enough as long as I can scroll to see more. Everything seems to work perfectly fine, I don't know why nothing is displayed...

Comment: white text on the white background ? change background color just for testing

Comment: I have no words to express how stupid I feel right now... Indeed, the text color was white but for some reasons, when I tested a couple of days ago it worked. Thanks a lot for your insight and please post your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you double checked that your adapter (data layer) is working correctly, the most likely you have the presentation layer problem, for example you could have a white text on the white background, in such cases [Hierarchy Viewer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/hierarchy-viewer/index.html) is very helpfull